# Thread.stop() deprecated almost 25 years back but never removed - Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, deprecated

I could not find any documentation, reference or rationale for this.

> **`Thread.stop()` has been deprecated since 1.2, almost quarter of a century back but has never been removed from JDK**

Why?

```
    @Deprecated(since="1.2", forRemoval=true)
     public final void stop() {
```

Comment: I guess they want you to `join`, as `stop` is quite ambiguous. Maybe `cancel` or `terminate` is a better word? I'm just guessing, but this seems like the terminology is open for interpretation, so they deprecated it to encourage people to use a more descriptive API, but don't want to remove it completely due to many people already using it.

Comment: My assumption (and that's all it is) is that older devices that may still be around that use  deprecated code  -- Including older medical devices, and infrastructure that's been around since the 90's -- If these devices are still in active use, it's probably best that developers can just work on them without having to rewrite them ..  Just a thought ..

Comment: @TedKleinBergman, `t.join()` is in no way a substitute for `t.stop()`. It should be obvious that `t.stop()` does something rather drastic to thread `t`, while `t.join()` does absolutely nothing at all to the thread. Also note: `t.stop()` is not deprecated because somebody thought "stop" was a bad name. It is deprecated because of what it does.

Comment: They only rather recently invented the “for removal” option for deprecated methods and classes. The `stop` method has only been marked so in either Java 18 or 19, so I would not expect it to be removed until either *in* the next LTS version (is that 20?) or perhaps rather *after* it (so in version 21). Nothing I know.

Comment: One big possible reason to keep in mind: there is no replacement! I really hope they don't get rid of it until there really is an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Because there could be old code that still executes it. Removing it would cause old code to no longer compile.

Sun and now Oracle have been cautious in terms of removing code that could require recompiles. Though lately they are slowly cleaning these things up. Because as you state, decades have passed, so its time.